# How to display content of StringBuilder as HTML?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, stringbuilder

I build a string that is supposed to be used to generate an HTML table.  I can't get the text to display as HTML though, it just writes as plain text.

Here's where I build the string:
StringBuilder HTMLTable = new StringBuilder();

```
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("<html>");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("<head>");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("<style type=\"text/css\">");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("    .thd {background: rgb(220,220,220); font: bold 10pt Arial; text-align: center;}");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("    .team {color: white; background: rgb(100,100,100); font: bold 10pt Arial; border-right: solid 2px black;}");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("    .winner {color: white; background: rgb(60,60,60); font: bold 10pt Arial;}");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("    .vs {font: bold 7pt Arial; border-right: solid 2px black;}");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("    td, th {padding: 3px 15px; border-right: dotted 2px rgb(200,200,200); text-align: right;}");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("    h1 {font: bold 14pt Arial; margin-top: 24pt;}");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("</style>");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("</head>");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("</html>");

    HTMLTable.AppendLine("<body>");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("<h1>Tournament Results</h1>");
    HTMLTable.AppendLine("<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">");
    for (int row = 0; row <= max_rows; row++)
    {
        cumulative_matches = 0;
        HTMLTable.AppendLine("    <tr>");
```

//  etc. etc.

And then I add this string to the viewbag associated with my .cshtml file.  I've tried things like:

```
 <text>@ViewBag.bracketHTML</text>
```

but that doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've noticed you have `</html>` before the `<body>`. Shouldn't it be at the very end of your markup (after `</body>`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should take @Zhihao's suggestion and fix the `HTML` end tag.

After that, this should work for you:

First, set the value of the HTML using the builder's `ToString()` function to a property of the `ViewBag` in the controller:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("<div>");
builder.AppendLine("Testing 123");
builder.AppendLine("</div>");

ViewBag.testing = builder.ToString();
```

Next, print it out using `Html.Raw()`:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.testing)
```

Seems to work well!

Answer (score 1):

There are a quite few ways to do it. You could it by either

```
@(new HtmlString(ViewBag.bracketHTML))
```

Or you could use

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.bracketHTML)
```

Or you could use @Html.Raw

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.bracketHTML)
```