# How to migrate usage of StringBuilder+TagBuilder for HTML rendering?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, tagbuilder

I am migrating projects from .NET Framework to .NET core. This question is about ASP MVC projects. I have a lot of `HtmlHelper` extension methods and many of these use the `TagBuilder` class to generate HTML elements while generating content into a `StringBuilder`.

```cs
public static HtmlString DisplayTiles(this IHtmlHelper html, TileDashboardModel groups, bool displayNotEnabled = false, bool displayUnauthorized = false)
{
    if (groups == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(groups));

    var content = new StringBuilder();
    var div = new TagBuilder("div");
    content.AppendLine(div.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));                     // does not build
    foreach (var group in groups.Groups)
    {
        DisplayTiles(html, content, group, displayNotEnabled, displayUnauthorized);
    }

    content.AppendLine(div.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));                       // does not build

    ////return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());                                  // does not build
    return new HtmlString(content.ToString());
}
```

In .NET Core the `TagBuilder.ToString()` method does not accept any argument. And rendering method seem to force you to use a `StringWriter`.

**What ways would you change the code to make it work?**

Consider: ease of change, memory consumption, extension method interference, code readability.

---

Related but different: [Migrating TagBuilder core methods from ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467715/migrating-tagbuilder-core-methods-from-asp-net-mvc-5-to-asp-net-core-net-5), [How to display content of StringBuilder as HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605292/how-to-display-content-of-stringbuilder-as-html)

Answer (score 1):

The ways I found are these, from the "best" to the worst. [full code here](https://gist.github.com/sandrock/a563db9f1b4e466c5d45b881a7a3f1d0)

#### Initial code

This only works with .NET Framework.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// The old way.
    /// </summary>
    [Fact]
    public void Test0()
    {
        var contents = new StringBuilder();
        var tag = new TagBuilder("div");
        tag.SetInnerText("hello");                              // method does not exist
    
        contents.Append(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));  // missing method overload
        Assert.Equal("<div>", contents.ToString());

        contents.Append(tag.InnerHtml);
        Assert.Equal("<div>hello", contents.ToString());

        contents.Append(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));    // missing method overload
        Assert.Equal("<div>hello</div>", contents.ToString());

        var result = MvcHtmlString.Create(contents.ToString()); // class does not exist
        Assert.Equal("<div>hello</div>", result.ToString());
    }
```

#### Minimal changes

This method focuses on minimal changes. You only need to change one type and declare a 3 extension methods.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Minimal code changes: extension methods.
    /// </summary>
    [Fact]
    public void Test4()
    {
        var contents = new StringWriter();                     // change this type
        var tag = new TagBuilder("div");
        tag.SetInnerText("hello");                             // 1 extension method

        contents.Append(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag)); // 2 extension methods
        Assert.Equal("<div>", contents.ToString());

        contents.Append(tag.InnerHtml);                        // 1 extension method
        Assert.Equal("<div>hello", contents.ToString());

        contents.Append(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));   // 2 extension methods
        Assert.Equal("<div>hello</div>", contents.ToString());
    }

    public static void SetInnerText(this TagBuilder tag, string value)
    {
        tag.InnerHtml.Append(value);
    }

    public static void Append(this StringWriter writer, IHtmlContent html)
    {
        html.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
    }

    public static IHtmlContent ToString(this TagBuilder tag, TagRenderMode mode)
    {
        if (mode == TagRenderMode.StartTag)
        {
            return tag.RenderStartTag();
        }
        else if (mode == TagRenderMode.EndTag)
        {
            return tag.RenderEndTag();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

#### Minimal call stack

Here a focus on not using extra methods; code changes a lot.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Use StringWriter instead of StringBuilder, no ext. methods.
    /// </summary>
    [Fact]
    public void Test3()
    {
        var contents = new StringWriter();                           // changed
        var tag = new TagBuilder("div");
        tag.InnerHtml.Append("hello");

        tag.RenderStartTag().WriteTo(contents, HtmlEncoder.Default); // changed
        Assert.Equal("<div>", contents.ToString());

        tag.RenderBody()?.WriteTo(contents, HtmlEncoder.Default);    // changed
        Assert.Equal("<div>hello", contents.ToString());

        tag.RenderEndTag().WriteTo(contents, HtmlEncoder.Default);   // changed
        Assert.Equal("<div>hello</div>", contents.ToString());
    }
```

#### The memory hogger

There is a known extension method that will allocate too much memory. Don't do this one.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Use Render methods and bad extension methods.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>So many StringWriters</remarks>
    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var contents = new StringBuilder();
        var tag = new TagBuilder("div");
        tag.InnerHtml.Append("hello");
        
        contents.AppendEx(tag.RenderStartTag());
        Assert.Equal("<div>", contents.ToString());

        contents.AppendEx(tag.RenderBody());
        Assert.Equal("<div>hello", contents.ToString());

        contents.AppendEx(tag.RenderEndTag());
        Assert.Equal("<div>hello</div>", contents.ToString());
    }

    public static void AppendEx(this StringBuilder builder, IHtmlContent? content)
    {
        if (content != null)
        {
            using (var writer = new StringWriter(builder))
            {
                content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a variant using `TagRenderMode`.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Set RenderMode and use extension methods.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>So many StringWriters</remarks>
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var contents = new StringBuilder();
        var tag = new TagBuilder("div");
        tag.InnerHtml.Append("hello");
        
        tag.TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.StartTag;
        contents.AppendEx(tag);
        Assert.Equal("<div>", contents.ToString());

        contents.AppendEx(tag.InnerHtml);
        Assert.Equal("<div>hello", contents.ToString());

        tag.TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.EndTag;
        contents.AppendEx(tag);
        Assert.Equal("<div>hello</div>", contents.ToString());
    }

    public static void AppendEx(this StringBuilder contents, TagBuilder tag)
    {
        // why do we need to do that? my StringBuilder is no good enough?
        using (var writer = new StringWriter(contents))
        {
            tag.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, do you know how to migrate when TagRendermode.Normal? There is no RenderNormal method in the TagBuilder class


`TagBuilder divMoreInfoText = new TagBuilder("span");
        divMoreInfoText.Attributes.Add("class", "helpText alert alert-info mrgn-tp-sm mrgn-bttm-sm");
        divMoreInfoText.Attributes.Add("style", "display: block");

        TagBuilder pHelpText = new TagBuilder("span");
        pHelpText.InnerHtml = text;
        divMoreInfoText.InnerHtml = pHelpText.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);`

Comment: I guess to be more clear, you have the following extension method. How would you handle TagRenderMode.Normal

`public static IHtmlContent ToString(this TagBuilder tag, TagRenderMode mode)
    {
        if (mode == TagRenderMode.StartTag)
        {
            return tag.RenderStartTag();
        }
        else if (mode == TagRenderMode.EndTag)
        {
            return tag.RenderEndTag();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

**The new `TagBuilder`** (in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering) **behaves very differently from the old `TagBuilder`** (in System.Web.Mvc). This makes code changes very hard; even harder if you do not have unit tests; you may get "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder" printed everywhere on your pages.

### The workaround

To avoid having a hard time migrating things for real, the fastest action is:

- copy the [old TagBuilder.cs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/main/src/System.Web.WebPages/Mvc/TagBuilder.cs) in your project
- rename it `TagBuilderOld` (to avoid type name conflicts)
- copy the [old TagRenderMode](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/main/src/System.Web.WebPages/Mvc/TagRenderMode.cs)
- rename it `TagRenderModeOld` (to avoid type name conflicts)
- import it in your helpers:
  `using TagBuilder = System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilderOld;`
  `using TagRenderMode = System.Web.Mvc.TagRenderModeOld;`
- you can also import the new one if you wish to become mad:
  `using TagBuilderNew = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder;`
  `using TagRenderModeNew = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.TagRenderMode;`

This way it works well. No "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder" everywhere on your pages.

Warning: this is a workaround! You will not get feature and security updates if you do that. See the other answers for a more serious way to solve the issue.